# Isekai reincarnation manga. Boy wakes up too soon because his soul is too strong

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

I read this manga about a year ago and I want to read it again but I can’t remember the name.

I think it’s about a 15 year old boy who died, then meets God, but is then transferred to another world. He is supposed to be hibernating until he is about 15, but his soul is too strong and he wakes up at 13 years old. He heads to a town and gets questioned by the guard and ends up telling the guard about how he met God and ended up in this world, while getting his answers checked by a truth-detection crystal ball.

Comment: Admittedly, goddesses are a bit more common, but the trope of dying, meeting a deity, then being transported to another world is fairly common. Do you remember how he died? What sort of powers he had? Does he have some sort of "system" that gives him a gamelike interface?

Comment: No I don’t remember but all I can remember is that he was supposed to wake up at 15 years old and when he wake up he has like a brief encounter with god and he then goes to a town the guard ask for identification he does not have one and also the guard is suspicious of him and take him to a room and he has a Crystal ball that can tells if someone is lying and the guard is shocked when he’s not lying